# Как в svg-документ вложить объекты из другого файла?

Tags: xml, svg

Кратко суть проблемы: имеется порядка сотни svg-файлов, в которых часть элементов повторяется. Можно ли эту повторяющуюся часть хранить в отдельном файле и загружать в эти svg?
Пример кода:

```
<g id="1">
 <path .../>
</g>
<g id="2">
 <path .../>
</g>
```

Требуется, к примеру, группу 1 вычленить из текущего документа и вставлять сюда из другого файла.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Александр. На локальном компе все-таки работать не будет, как я понимаю?
И еще маленький вопрос: Что такое "baseProfile="full"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для  многократного использования части кода SVG из одного файла в других файлах применяется команда

```
<use xlink:href="lib.svg#g1" x="15" y="15" />
```

где, `lib.svg` - файл, в котором находится группа 1 с присвоенным `id="g1"` (имя должно начинаться с буквы, но не с цифры).
Для повторного использования части кода в том же файле:

```
<use xlink:href="#g1" x="15" y="15" />
```

Comment: Вроде бы все правильно, но почему-то не работает ((

Comment: xml - это точность до запятой, проверьте всё еще раз.
Все файлы *.svg разместите в одной директории.
Попробуйте присвоить id не группе, а path

Comment: В шапке файла должна быть обязательно эта строка объявления пространства имен, без нее ссылки не работают

   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"

Comment: Вот, например, основной файл:

    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"/>
    <use xlink:href="star.svg#g1"/>
    <polygon fill="lime" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" points="850,75 958,137.5 958,262.5 850,325 742,262.6 742,137.5"/>
    </svg>

Comment: Вот файл star.svg

    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <g id="g1">
    <polygon fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" points="350,75 379,161 469,161 397,215 423,301 350,250 277,301 303,215 231,161 321,161" />
    </g>
    </svg>

Comment: Пробовал назначать id полигону - результат тот же - добавляемый элемент не отображается. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: В Firefox работает - звездочка видна и шестиугольник, в остальных браузерах виден только шестиугольник. Пробую разобраться.

Comment: Проверил все варианты:
На локальном компе работает корректно только в Firefox.
В денвере работает во всех браузерах
Загрузил файлы на свой интернет сайт, тоже все нормально работает и при просмотре сафари, Опера, Яндекс браузер и гугловский Хром.
Шапку изменил, так как doctype для SVG не рекомендуют употреблять
Ширину, высоту для SVG и viewBox лучше писать в одних единицах
Повторяемый код лучше размещать в секции  из парных тегов defs
Ваш файл star.svg моя редакция - st1.svg

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg  version="1.1" width="600" height="200"
        viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
      <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"/>
        <use xlink:href="st1.svg#star1"/>
          <polygon fill="lime" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" points="850,75 958,137.5 958,262.5 850,325 742,262.6 742,137.5"/>    
 </svg>